# returning a warp filter from function

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'm using [warp](https://crates.io/crates/warp) to create a server in Rust. And let's say I have these two routes setup.

```rust
let route_one = warp::get().and(warp::path("path1")).map(|| warp::reply());
let route_two = warp::get().and(warp::path("path2")).map(|| warp::reply());

warp::serve(route_one.or(route_two))
    .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000))
    .await;
```

**I would like to move the routes into their own function. What would the return type be?**

For instance:

```rust
async fn get_route_one() {
     warp::get().and(warp::path("path1")).map(|| warp::reply())
}

async fn get_route_two() {
     warp::get().and(warp::path("path1")).map(|| warp::reply())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    warp::serve(get_route_one().or(get_route_two()))
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000))
        .await;
}
```

I've tried using `warp:Filter` and multiple variations of it, but I haven't found a return type that compiles.

*P.S. I know in this example extracting out the filters into their own functions just complicates things, but I have a situation where it may actually simplify things.*

Answer (score 2):

It'll depend on your actual types but something in the vicinity of `impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection>`. I'll recommend to check out the [todos example](https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp/blob/master/examples/todos.rs) for inspiration.

Comment: Seems to work better than anything I've tried, though I'm still getting an error. note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `impl warp::Future: warp::filter::FilterBase`
      which is required by `impl warp::Future: warp::Filter`
      `&impl warp::Future: warp::filter::FilterBase`
      which is required by `&impl warp::Future: warp::Filter`
      `&mut impl warp::Future: warp::filter::FilterBase`
      which is required by `&mut impl warp::Future: warp::Filter`

It may be because I'm very new to warp and Rust, so I don't know what this means. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm using `.map` whereas the todo example uses `.and_then`?

Answer (score 2):

This is what we do in our own projects. For instance, we may have an endpoint like this:

```
pub async fn index(cfg: crate::settings::Settings) -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    info!("Index endpoint called");
    Ok(warp::reply::with_status(
        format!("Welcome to Our API Version {}", cfg.version),
        http::StatusCode::OK,
    ))
}
```

And we may have another endpoint like this:

```
pub async fn health() -> Result<impl warp::Reply, warp::Rejection> {
    Ok(warp::reply::with_status("OK", http::StatusCode::OK))
}
```

We can build a function that wraps these up like this:

```
use warp::Filter;

/// External endpoints: /v1/base
pub fn base_endpoints(
    config: crate::settings::Settings,
) -> impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {

    let base_endpoints_trunk = warp::path("v1").and(warp::path("base"));
    let index = base_endpoints_trunk
        .and(warp::get())
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and(crate::settings::with_cfg(config.clone()))
        .and_then(index);
    let health = base_endpoints_trunk
        .and(warp::get())
        .and(warp::path("health"))
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .and_then(health);

    index.or(health)
}
```

Then, inside our `main`, we can do something like this:

```
let base = endpoints::base_endpoints(CONFIG.clone());

warp::serve(base.recover(errors::handle_rejection)).run(([0, 0, 0, 0], 9000)).await
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me -- both your example and my more complex use case. (The other answers were helpful as a starting point, but didn't resolve my issues).

The way I got it to work was by removing `async` since we don't need function to be async just to generate a filter and it works around the fact that Rust compiler is a little finicky these days for use cases like these:

```
use warp::Filter;

fn get_route_one() 
-> impl Filter<Extract = (impl warp::Reply + 'static,), Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone  + 'static {

     warp::get().and(warp::path("path1")).map(|| warp::reply())
}

fn get_route_two() 
-> impl Filter<Extract = (impl warp::Reply + 'static,), Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone  + 'static {
     warp::get().and(warp::path("path1")).map(|| warp::reply())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    warp::serve(get_route_one().or(get_route_two()))
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000))
        .await;
}
```